# How to set the default Yaw angle for the robot in Gazebo launchfile?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the launch file, there is a format for setting the XYZ coordinates, like this:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
    <arg name="x_pos" default="-1.0"/>
    <arg name="y_pos" default="-6.0"/>
    <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>
```

But I want to set the robot`s Yaw or Roll, pitch, or Quaternion, How to set them or what the code is, like this:

```
<arg name="x_pos" default="-1.0"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381528/how-to-set-the-default-yaw-angle-for-the-robot-in-gazebo-launchfile?/) by [Guapiii](https://answers.ros.org/users/73386/guapiii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> In the launch file

Which launch file are you talking about ? You should include it in your question, or at least tell the node you are trying to launch.

I'm assuming that you want to launch a turtlebot simulation, so it's the node `spawn_model`  from the package `gazebo_ros` that will handle the initial position. You should have something like this in your launch file :

```
<node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
```

Now if you look at all the arguments of the script `spawn_model` [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/scripts/spawn_model#L42-L68) you will see this :

```
-x <x in meters> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
-y <y in meters> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
-z <z in meters> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
-R <roll in radians> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
-P <pitch in radians> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
-Y <yaw in radians> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
```

So you just have to add this in the `args` of the node `spawn_model`, after  `-z $(arg z_pos)` for example : `-R $(arg ROLL)` , with `ROLL` being the argument name that you should define at the beginning of your launch file.

---

Edit :
You seem to have a little confusion with the arguments of a launch file, the name isn't relevant at all, it's like declaring a variable. The important part is the value you assign to it. You should have a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg) for more explanations.

In your case you have this :

```
<node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
```

You give to the node `spawn_model` a list of arguments, for example you specify the `x` value by adding -`x VALUE` where `VALUE` is set at the beginning of your launch file like this :

```
<arg name="x_pos" default="-1.0"/>
```

So if you want to set the roll, pitch or yaw you have to add in the list `-R` for the roll, `-P` for the pitch and `-Y` for the yaw. Like this :

```
<arg name="roll" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="pitch" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="yaw" default="0.0"/>
<node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -R $(arg roll) -P $(arg pitch) -Y $(arg yaw) -param robot_description" />
```

(you can name the arguments whatever you want, you just need to use them properly)

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2021-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guapiii](https://answers.ros.org/users/73386/guapiii/) on 2021-07-07**:
I am sorry for not being clear enough in my question. The launch file i am using is `ros/melodic/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/turtlebot3_world.launch`
I used your method to add: `<arg name="YAW" default="1.5"/>` after  `<arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>`
But it doesn`t work

**Comment by [Guapiii](https://answers.ros.org/users/73386/guapiii/) on 2021-07-08**:
It is true that I do not know enough about the parameters of the launch file.
I used your method successfully!
Thank you very much for your answer!